# Seeking shapefiles for Indian Constituencies?

Tags: data, india

The GIS data officially provided by the government is only available as PDF maps. Some people have [shared shapefiles](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~sandip/data.html) for the previous delimitation but these are outdated. Parliamentary constituency data can be also be viewed [here](http://www.google.co.in/elections/ed/in/districts) but no source has been provided.

Would anyone know a way to get GIS data for the assembly and parliamentary constituencies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the boundaries in Shapefile format available under [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 2.5 India](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/in/) license:

https://github.com/datameet/maps/tree/master/parliamentary-constituencies

Answer (score -1):

This is the link I found for both parliamentary and state assembly: http://projects.datameet.org/maps/assembly-constituencies/